# How is $\{x \in A | f(x) \notin A \} = \overline{ \{ x \in A | f(x) \in A \}}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was reading Discrete Math book when I came across a solution which used the following equality.

$\{x \in A | f(x) \notin A \} = \overline{ \{ x \in A | f(x) \in A \}}$

How can it be proved?

Comment: If $f : B\to C$ is a function with $A\subset B\cap C$, then for all $x\in A$, $f(x)\in A$ or not, the two options being mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 3):

As long as $\overline X$ is defined as $A\setminus X$, it is more generally true that
$$\{\,x\in A\mid \Phi(x)\,\}=\overline{\{\,x\in A\mid \neg \Phi(x)\,\}}.$$ 
To see this note that 
$$ \begin{align}x\in\overline{\{\,x\in A\mid \neg \Phi(x)\,\}}&\iff x\in A\land \neg(x\in A\land\neg \Phi(x))\\
&\iff x\in A\land(x\notin A\lor \neg\neg\Phi(x)\\
&\iff x\in A\land \Phi(x)\\&\iff x\in\{\,x\in A\mid \Phi(x)\,\}\end{align}$$

Here, you have $\Phi(x)\equiv f(x)\in A$ and so $\neg\Phi(x)\equiv f(x)\notin A$.

Comment: Where is the first $x\in A$ in $ x\in A\land \neg(x\in A\land\neg \Phi(x)) $ coming from? And how did you go about the last equivalence, going from predicate logic to generalizing the set?

Answer (score 2):

For every $x\in A$, either $f(x)\in A$ or $f(x)\not\in A$, so $$\{x\in A\mid f(x)\not\in A\}\cup\{x\in A\mid f(x)\in A\}=A.$$
Also, for no $x$ can we have $f(x)\in A$ and $f(x)\not\in A$, so
$$\{x\in A\mid f(x)\not\in A\}\cap\{x\in A\mid f(x)\in A\}=\varnothing.$$
Thus the two sets are complements of each other with respect to $A$.